# How to convert OpenCV Java BGR Image Matrix to RGB?

Tags: python, java, image, opencv, computer-vision

In python we can do the following to convert CV BGR value to RGB

```
im = cv2.imread("image.jpg") # BGR
im = im.transpose((2, 0, 1))[::-1]  # HWC to CHW, BGR to RGB
```

I can't figure out how to do this with Java.
I've tried the following but it gives a completely different value when the second line is executed.

```
Mat image = Imgcodecs.imread("image.jpg"); // BGR matches the python thus far
Imgproc.cvtColor(image, image, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2BGR); // doesnt match the python
```

Comment: Can you show the results?

Comment: In Python you not only convert to RGB, but you also change the order of dimensions of the array, going from interleaved (the three values for each pixel being together in memory) to planar order (all the red values being together, and all the green values being together, etc). Why do you need this? Are you sure you want to copy this in Java?

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty straight forward, and you already got the right function (`cvtColor()`).

Are you using the right flag ? `COLOR_RGB2BGR` means converting RGB->BGR, but you say you want BGR->RGB ? That would be `COLOR_BGR2RGB`. 
Here is the full list: https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d8/d01/group__imgproc__color__conversions.html

You can also tell `imread()` in what color space to read the image file, btw: 
`Mat cv::imread  (const String& filename, int flags = IMREAD_COLOR)` 
https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d4/da8/group__imgcodecs.html#ga288b8b3da0892bd651fce07b3bbd3a56

Comment: Since both BGR to RGB and RGB to BGR involve swapping the 1st and 3rd channels, I would guess there’s no difference between `COLOR_RGB2BGR` and `COLOR_BGR2RGB`.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Yes, absolutely no difference, since `COLOR_RGB2BGR == COLOR_BGR2RGB`